# How to disable csh's precmd output log to the terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, csh

When I type a command within **csh**, it outputs

```
[d88@180_itsys ~]$ ls
csh.bak  test  test001  test002  test003
[1]  + Done                          ( set noglob; /bin/echo `date +%F-%H:%M:%S:%N` `who am i` %::%$_ | nohup sock_client )
[1] 5456
```

My .cshrc is:

```
alias precmd 'set noglob;  /bin/echo `date +%F-%H:%M:%S:%N` `who am i`  %::%$_ | nohup sock_client &; unset noglob'
```

**sock_client** is a socket client written by C. How to make command not output log lines starting with `[1]`? not to change the command to type

Comment: I suggest avoid using `csh` interactively. Consider [zsh](http://zsh.org/) or [fish](http://fishshell.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a subshell and redirect its standard output to `/dev/null`.

```
alias precmd '(set noglob;  /bin/echo `date +%F-%H:%M:%S:%N` `who am i`  %::%$_ | nohup sock_client &; unset noglob)>/dev/null'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output this :

```
your_command | awk '{if(!($1=="[1]")){print}}'
```

Comment: Mention this in the question then :D